# angular material mat-button-toggle-group default value not set as undefined

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need component with three states for search, and default value as `undefined`. so i use  `mat-button-toggle-group` but default value not effect on component design.

html:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group 
[(ngModel)]="myValue" 
[value]="myValue" aria-label="Font Style">
  <mat-button-toggle [value]="1">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle [value]="undefined">Italic</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle [value]="0">Underline</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
{{'myValue:'+myValue}}
```

ts:

```
  myValue:number;
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/basic-button-toggles-default-undefied-value)

anyone can help me?

Comment: Why do you want to use undefined as a value anyway? You can just change the value for the 'Italic' option to -1 and then in the component code once when you fetch the data via API or as a component input (OnChanges), or in a component OnInit, do a comparison like this: this.buttonValue ? this.buttonValue : -1, and it will work just fine.

Comment: @Semir Deljić i have an object for search, and bind fields of that to components. one of them have zero/one value. as you know, in search until user not fill values, i can't take effect result values. therefore i need default value for empty state. i need undefined only for renew searchObject and reset all search filters.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yw9zyq-o1glji

```html
<mat-button-toggle-group name="fontStyle" 
#group="matButtonToggleGroup" 
[value]="2" aria-label="Font Style">
  <mat-button-toggle [value]="1">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle [value]="2">Italic</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle [value]="0">Underline</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
{{'myValue:'+group.value}}
```

And do not use undefined as a value. You can use any other number or value.

Comment: assume that i have `SearchFilter` object with a field like `myValue`. when i renew `SearchFilter`, all field set to undefined. therefore default value should be 'undefined'

Comment: That example is not working if you change values to string.

Answer (score 0):

You have notice that the `undefined` value is treated as string. And `myValue` type is `number`.

```js
<mat-button-toggle-group 
 value="undefined"
 (change)="myValue = $event ? $event.value : undefined"
 aria-label="Font Style">
  <mat-button-toggle [value]="1">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="undefined">Italic</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle [value]="0">Underline</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
{{'myValue:'+myValue}}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it is a bug by angular. More informations here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/25472

Comment: Please provide a summary of what is the bug exactly.

Comment: Please share how to resolve the problem

Comment: while I think this very very marginally scrapes by as being a valid answer, it would be much better if you would please expand. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587. why does it happen? in what version is it fixed? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/426660/11107541